# Android Network Address

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to connect an android app to a mysql database using the mysql-connector.  The database, however, is on a computer with an active wifi hotspot that the app would (probably?) need to connect to.  I am not sure which network address to use.  Currently I am using the ip of that computer (128.xxx.xx.xxx) but I get an error: `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2`.  I'm think that I'm not actually connecting to the database, but I'm not sure.  Any suggestions would be great!

`jdbc:mysql://128.xxx.xx.xxx:3306/databaseName`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your computer and your phone (where your app is running at) need to be connected on the same network.
I would strongly advice you **NOT** to connect to a database via android, since the code could be deobfuscated and then everybody could read the mysql login credentials. It's better to develop an API or such, to be the *middleman* between your app and the mysql server.

To get your local machines IP(Windows):

Open command prompt and type: **ipconfig**
The local IP will be the IPv4 address

[image]

Comment: Even when connecting to the same network, I am not able to connect to the mysql server; it gives the following error: `java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #63 bootstrap method`